# Django getting Type error in post image create function view

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-views

The code below is getting error `TypeError: post_image_create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post'` I want to add multiple images to a django form asynchronously before form submit.I have the Javascript code for uploading of the images on the client side and asynchronously adds it to my server. All I need to do is give it a endpoint

I would be grateful for any help.

**MODELS**

```
class FileModel(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='stories', blank=True, null=True)
```

**VIEWS**

```
def post_image_create(request, post):
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            FileModel.objects.create(file=f)


class NewsCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = FileForm
    template_name = 'news/news_create.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = self.request.user
        post_image_create(request=self.request, post=post)  # This function is defined above
        post.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Check this documentation on how to get the csrf-token for ajax requests [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is saying that your request function is missing an argument. `TypeError: post_image_create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'post'`.

In your view function, you define `def post_image_create(request, post):` but in your urls.py you have it set up as :`path('new_image/', views.post_image_create, name='new_image')` If you want to pass a parameter you need to set set that up in your urls.py url router.

BUT that isn't used for passing post data. You can access post data using the request object. Change your view function to be:

```
def post_image_create(request):
  if(request.method == "POST"):
    files = request.FILES 
     ...then do stuff
```

Here it is in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method

and more about passing parameter in urls.py to a view function: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: @afi any update from that previous update? I don't think this is the best way to go about solving this, since updating my answer and updating your question back and forth will obscure the original problem you had and the original fix suggested. Maybe you should open a new question.

Comment: yes dear i'm try to find the solution of the problem. your answer is right for me...